# How to delete a file/object stored in an AWS S3 bucket, using the Android SDK?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-sdk-android

I have searched the [latest AWS docs for the Android SDK,](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/sdk/android/storage) on the official site. Unfortunately I couldn't find anything related to this. How can I delete a particular -- or multiple -- file(s) or object(s) *using the Android SDK*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution that works, if anyone comes looking it may help, did not find this in the docs of AWS for Android SDk, and the Amplify framework is in preview stage maybe it will come soon after few months. Till then the the solution is:

```js
new Thread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    s3Client.deleteObject(bucketName, filePath);
  }
}).start();
```

And always create a new thread or else it will throw error.
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

As of mid-2020, the preferred approach for this is to use the AWS Amplify library for Android.

See [the documentation for `remove()`, in the Storage category](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/remove/q/platform/android). It suggests to do (in Java):

```java
Amplify.Storage.remove(
    "myUploadedFileName.txt",
    result -> Log.i("MyAmplifyApp", "Successfully removed: " + result.getKey()),
    error -> Log.e("MyAmplifyApp", "Remove failure", error)
);
```

***OR*** (in Kotlin):

```kotlin
Amplify.Storage.remove(
    "myUploadedFileName.txt",
    { result -> Log.i("MyAmplifyApp", "Successfully removed: " + result.getKey()) },
    { error -> Log.e("MyAmplifyApp", "Remove failure", error) }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the `Amplify.Storage.remove` method in the amplify official doc itself.
Here is the [link](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/android/storage)

```java
private void removeFile() {
    Amplify.Storage.remove(
        "myUploadedFileName.txt",
        new ResultListener<StorageRemoveResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(StorageRemoveResult storageRemoveResult) {
                Log.i("StorageQuickStart", "Successfully removed: " + storageRemoveResult.getKey());
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable error) {
                Log.e("StorageQuickStart", error.getMessage());
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: thank u Sir but actually I was looking for a solution using Android Sdk of Aws not Amplify Framework which is said is in the development phase not for production usage.

Comment: But in your question you were asked about amplify.

Comment: FYI:  AWS iOS and Android SDK is now part of the Amplify Framework. You can follow the above documentation.

Comment: But Sir at the beginning of Amplify framework page its written its still is in preview stage and not for development purpose now.

Comment: ^ Note: As of mid 2020, Amplify is not in preview anymore.